# how to position a div for all screen resolutions

Tags: css, position

I need to place a div in certain part of my web page. so i coded as following,

```
<div style='position:absolute;top:500px;margin-left:300px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000000;height:100px;'></div>
```

When i checked this page in a 19 inch monitor it is placed where i wanted. but i checked the same page in a 17 inch monitor it is placed 50-70 px more on the left side.

so how should i placed the div in the same place for all screen resolution. This question may seems simple, but i'm not that much familiar to css so any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The monitor size should have very little to do with this issue... what about the size of the user's browser window?

Comment: may be you should use % instead of pixels for defining positions and size.

Comment: @Sparky672: 17 in monitor has 1024*768 and 19 inch monitor has 1366 * 768 resolution.

Comment: @ChingPing  i tried now, but it still goes more on the left side when i check in 17" monitor.

Comment: how about a js fiddle .. it could be your content? not that item.. possibly

Comment: @Sekar, again... the size of the monitor has almost nothing to do with your issue.  You can still have a 900 pixel wide browser window open on both.  Not everyone opens their browser window to full screen width especially when today's screens are typically larger than 17 or 19".  If resolution is a critical issue for your design, then you need to examine the viewport (browser size) and not the monitor (desktop size).

Comment: @Sparky672 You mean try to set left alignment based on the browser width something like that , right? i'll give a try now...

Comment: @Sparky672 Thanks for all your efforts, specially for you. yes, the monitor size nothing to here. I solved my issue and will post as answer, so someday it might help someone.. Thanks 4 all:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially the div had no parent elements, so it is directly under body element. so when i tried to set left:100px, it is counted from leftmost part in the browser.

But i already a had div with 900px with some content and half of the space(vertically) in this div was empty. this is where i wanted to place 100px div.

So i set the 900px position to relative and taken the 100px into 900px div. now this div is positioned "absolute" to the parent element.

Now if i set left:100px to the div its counted from its parent element which is positioned relatively.

The Concept is simple,

**Absolute positioning works by using the next available parent container that is positioned (absolutely or relatively)**

Have a look at this link it helped to achieve this, [absolute postioning](http://www.xantec.com.my/xblog/?p=75)

Answer (score 1):

May be you want an `absolute position` `div` `horizontally` `center` then write like this 
CSS:

```
div{
  position:absolute;
  top:500px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  left:50%;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  height:100px;
}
```

& you can use `media query` for different resolution check this http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: I don't want to center it, but the div should be placed in same part of the webpage for all resolutions. I tried to % for left alignment but it still goes more left when i see in the 17" monitor